# Bugs/issues list for Visual Studio 2008/2010

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there an official / unofficial list of bugs and issues in Visual Studio, or any of its components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here on Microsoft Connect:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?FeedbackType=1&Status=1&Scope=0&SortOrder=15&TabView=0

Answer (score 1):

http://connect.microsoft.com/directory/accepting-bugs

Comment: I'm sure Microsoft have internal tracking tools, but Connect is the public "view", yes.