# How can I give Microsoft feedback regarding Windows CE support in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compact-framework

I like using Visual Studio 2010, but miss having support for Smart Device Projects and Compact Framework (i.e. Windows CE, Pocket PC and Smart Phone).

Where and how can I make my voice heard? Does MS have a public "feature requests" site where I could propose / vote on such support?

Comment: This is annoying, my ASP.NET app is stuck at 3.5 because it shares a project with a CE device.

Comment: This seems better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. It's not so much about programming as it is ways for programmers to tell a company how they can improve a tool for them. Also, this should at least be CW if it remains here.

Comment: @gnovice @Will - Please reopen and I will switch this to CW.

Comment: It may be an edge case, but I would consider this on-topic as a tools question. Similar questions: [Bugs/issues list for Visual Studio 2008/2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528384/bugs-issues-list-for-visual-studio-2008-2010), [How do I submit a bug to microsoft?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175389/how-do-i-submit-a-bug-to-microsoft)

Answer (score 2):

Go [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/595712/no-support-for-windows-ce-and-compact-framework-development-in-vs2010?wa=wsignin1.0) and vote for it to be added in.

Comment: It is up to 100 now :) It talks about it not being there because of the Forms Designer. Does anyone actually use that? I'd be fine if that feature didn't make the upgrade.

Comment: 162 (after mine).  Not a huge number yet, but keep adding to it.